# How to outprint json with php on remote folder

Tags: php, json, web, server

What is the correct way to outprint this type of .json file using php?
I have a remote folder that receives images via a app then it is suppose to  displays those same images from a .json file, in short the gallery pulls the image link from a json file. The function to update the json file is complete however the correct process to write the json file using php is beyond my knowledge and I need help. My working json file looks like this

```
 {
"status": true,
"data": {
    "products": [ 
        {
            "id": "4342",
            "name": "Pattern - Fractal Wallpaper",
            "image_url": "http_my_server"
        },
        {
            "id": "431",
            "name": "Mickey Mouse",
            "image_url": "http_my_server"
        }
    ]
}
```

my php outprint looks like this and it doesn't work

```
 [{"image_url":"IMG_20160919_112859.jpg"}][{"image_url":"IMG_20160919_112859.jpg"},{"image_url":"IMG_20160919_102513.jpg"}][{"image_url":"IMG_20160919_112859.jpg"}
```

Comment: Please write down what you tried so far and be more clear to your question.

Comment: this is lmy code so far 'if(is_dir($dir)){
    if($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while(($image_url = readdir($dh)) != false){
            if($image_url != "." and $image_url != ".."){
               $image_url_array[] = 
          array  
               ('image_url' => $image_url); // Add the file to the array
        

echo json_encode($image_url_array);'

Comment: Please add in question.

Comment: how to outprint the above json using php

Comment: I need to outprint the file in the above format displaying Size, FileType and Location. And I don't know how to do this.

Comment: How you are getting name field value?

Comment: it is suppose to be the time stamp that is generated by default

Comment: Try something like this:
$output = array();
    $output['status'] = true;
    $output['products'] = array();
    foreach($images as $key => $image) {
        $output['products'][$key]['id'] = 'id';
        $output['products'][$key]['name'] = 'name';
        $output['products'][$key]['image'] = 'image url';
    }
    echo json_encode($output);